# Refactoring to async/await

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

I'm just learning how to use async/await and Im trying to refactor my callbacks to use it.

I just want to know if Im doing it right... or if someone could explain it to me like you're talking to a 10 year old.

this is the code im trying to refactor

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn,  async function(req, res) {
//lookup book using id

var username = req.user.username;
var userId = req.user._id;
var available = req.body.available;
var daysToAdd = 2;
var reservedBy = {username: username, userId: userId, available: available};

Book.findById(req.params.id, function(err, book) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        //create new reserve name

        Reserve.create(reservedBy, function(err, reserve) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                reservedBy.username)
                // console.log("new reserves username " + reservedBy.available)
                reserve.returnDate = reserve.borrowDate.setDate(reserve.borrowDate.getDate() + daysToAdd);
                reserve.reserved.id = reservedBy.userId;
                reserve.reserved.username = reservedBy.username;
                // //save review
                reserve.save();
                //connect reserve user to book
                //redirect to book show page
                book.reserves.push(reserve);
                if (book.available < 1) {
                    req.flash("error", "There are no more available books");
                    res.redirect("/library/" + book._id);
                } else {
                    book.available--;
                    book.save();
                    res.redirect("/library/" + book._id);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

and this is what I refactored so far..

```
try {
    let book = await Book.findById(req.params.id);
    let reserve = await Reserve.create(reservedBy);

    reserve.returnDate = reserve.borrowDate.setDate(reserve.borrowDate.getDate() + daysToAdd);
    reserve.reserved.id = reservedBy.userId;
    reserve.reserved.username = reservedBy.username;
    reserve.save();

    book.reserves.push(reserve);
    if (book.available < 1) {
        req.flash("error", "There are no more available books");
        res.redirect("/library/" + book._id);
    } else {
        book.available--;
        book.save();
        res.redirect("/library/" + book._id);
    }

} catch(err) {
  req.flash('error', 'Something went wrong!');
  res.redirect('back');
}
```

Comment: And what stops you from continuing? What issues you have?

Comment: The question doesn't even mention that it's Mongoose while this is crucial here.

Comment: If you're talking about the structure of your refactored code, I think you're doing fine. Just remember that you can do stuff in between `await` lines. Like you can do something to the `book` result of `await Book.findById()` before proceeding to the next `await` line.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that I copied the incomplete refactored code that I was doing. I've just editted it to post the right refactored one.

Comment: You're doing it correct, more or less. `await reserve.save()` is mandatory. Do you have specific problems with implementation? The question is offtopic without problem statement.

Comment: umm no.. i don't have problems with implementation. i just wanted to know if I'm on the right track. why is `await reserve.save()` mandatory?